# Add a space on top of a #page HTML link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I have a link that loads a section within the same page, the link will make the section clicked on load at the top of the browser window, I need to somehow add a space/gap of like 100px on top of all these sections that are linked like this.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
The link to section
<a href="#page">Page</a>


The section
<a id="page"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css just set the [padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding-top) to 100px (you'll need some form of CSS selector to target only the 'correct' links):

```
a.someCssClassOrSelector {
  padding-top: 100px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scroll-padding-top` is exactly what you've looking for. See:

```css
  html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 8.5rem;
}
```